# How to know default value or stored value

Tags: sql-server

I have a table field which has a default value '0' and users can store any numeric values for it. For my application I need to know the user has stored any value or not.

Is there any way to find out the column in the query returns it's default value or stored value with MSSQL?

Comment: Can you please explain along with examples

Comment: Okay I will explain more with ex.

Comment: There's no way of knowing after the event if a 0 is stored because they explicitly supplied that value at insert time or it was supplied by the default. If that's what you are asking.

Comment: @MartinSmith YES. That's what I want to know. Thanks.

Comment: You would need to add a column with a flag and modify inserts/updates on that table I'm affraid

Comment: If the user can enter a value that is the same as the default value, there is no built in way to know if that value was stored by the user. You will have to either drop the default value (keep null instead) or add another column that will indicate that the value was entered by a user.

Comment: You need a `Log Table` or `ActionDate` column.

Comment: In case it's not clear from the other comments, default values *are* stored values - they're used at `INSERT` time and only at that time. E.g. if you change the default value for a column, it won't magically change the values for rows that were previously inserted and used the default at that time.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question as stated is that a query that **returns** existing rows from the database will **always return the stored value**.

A "default value" for a column is only used during inserts:

1. If the column, during the insert, has a value provided for it, use that value
2. If the column, during the insert, does not have a value provided for it, use the default value (if one is specified)

Afterwards it is not possible to know if a default value for 0 was used or if the insert provided the value 0 for the column.

So a *query* will always return the stored value.

---

Corollary:

- Changing the default value setting for a field does not change existing rows that was inserted using the old default value. They will keep their current values.
- Adding a default value for a field that allows `null` does not set the value of this field for existing rows with `null` in them to this new default value, again they will keep their existing values (`null`).

---

You can monkey around with triggers and stuff to detect that no value was provided, and then update the row with a "default value" as well as set a checkmark or similar in a separate column to indicate that "a default value was provided" but there is no mechanism built into SQL Server to do this for you easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
begin tran

insert into [dbo].[BuyOnlineCartMaster] (OfferAmt)values(0) 
        -- inserting value to some other column, 

select NetAmt from [BuyOnlineCartMaster] where CartID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()  
        -- default value is genereted in the required feild


rollback tran
```

The select statement gives the default value

make this as a procedure call or something

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
use tempdb

 create table #ttt 
(
        c1 int identity not null,
        c2 int not null,
        c3 int default -1,
        c4 as (case when c3 < 0 then c3+1 else c3 end),
        c5 as (case when c3 < 0 then 'DEFAULT VALUE' else 'USER SUPPLIED' end)
)


insert into #ttt values (10, 20)
insert into #ttt values (11, 21)
insert into #ttt (c2) values (20)

select * from #ttt

/*For selections, you can use */
Select C1, C2, C4 from #ttt
```

Comment: After `insert into #ttt values (-1, 20)` by a user, `select c2, c4, c5 from #ttt` will return 20, 0, 'DEFAULT VALUE'. Though a pretty clever solution, it demonstrates that you can't distinguish the situation where a user explicitly sets a column to the default value from the situation where it was set because it was not provided by the user.